# How can I get a tp link TL-wn722n to work in my Kali VM?

Tags: kali-linux

I can't figure out how to get my usb wifi adapter to be recognized by iwconfig. When I type 'lsusb' into the terminal I get this back:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Answer (score 2):

The VM software that you are using probably has an option to pass USB devices on through to the OS running in an active VM. You need to activate that.

You don't mention what virtualization software you are using, so I cannot say where the option would be. Usually it's in a Settings menu, or it's an option on the launch command itself.